# Pass Unified Service Desk Context Parameter value inside Javascript webresource CRM

Tags: javascript, crm, unified-service-desk

I am working on CRM 8.2 and Unified Service Desk 4.1. Now, there is a requirement where i want to pass some parameter values from within inside Unified Service Desk Data Parameters to JavaScript Webresource.

I have seen some articles where we can inject our data to javaScript but only for Unified Interface Pages. But mine are not those.

My actual requirement is to show/hide ribbon button on basis of **USD Data parameter** value, so if there is any workaround then I can work on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do so.
I just answered the other day for passing form context to webresource.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920244/display-external-application-forms-within-microsoft-dynamics-365/59927555?noredirect=1#comment105980620_59927555)

But for your specific case, you need Ribbon workbench and form context and primary context. This is also directly possible and you can do so.
Here is the perfect [example](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/alfwynjordan/2019/10/02/getting-dynamics-365-formcontext-from-ribbon-workbench) for you.
I have used exact same in lot of my projects.

Comment: Hi @AnkUser . Appreciatw your response but you may have misunderstood my question. I am talking about passing values from Unified Service Desk Data Parameters not from form context